# Need to refresh function upon action

Tags: javascript, css

First off, I'm not all too familiar with Javascript so simple terms helps!

I'm trying to write a script to add this w3-light-grey attribute to the Image1 modal every single time the openModal function is run. Currently, I have multiple modals and the w3-light-gray attribute is only added to the first Image1 item upon openModal function. Clicking around within multiple modals to move that w3-light-gray attribute means that technically the last interacted item contains that w3-light-grey attribute, whereas I want the first Image1 item to always have that as soon as the openModal function is run.

I'm providing my script in hopes this is enough but I can provide my full HTML/CSS if that's needed for context.

```
<script>

// open the modal with only image 1 displayed

function openModal(modalId) {

      document.getElementById(modalId).style.display='block';
      document.getElementById(modalId+'Image1').classList.add('w3-light-grey');
      document.getElementById(modalId+'Image1').style.display='block';
      document.getElementById(modalId+'Image2').style.display='none';
    }

function openImgtype(evt, imgtypeName) {

  var i, x, tablinks;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("imgtype");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].classList.remove("w3-light-grey");
  }
  document.getElementById(imgtypeName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.classList.add("w3-light-grey");
}

</script>

<!-- MODAL 5 Primary Colours Toys -->

<div id="toyscard" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content w3-animate-zoom">

    <span onclick="document.getElementById('toyscard').style.display='none'" class="button closebtn">×</span>
    <div class="desc">
    <h1>Primary Colours, Inc.</h1>
    <h2>TOYS Group Show Postcard and Graphics</h2>
      <p>This is the postcard design for Primary Colours, Inc.'s annual 
holiday group show, TOYS. Also shown are accompanying web graphics 
advertising the show. The postcard was a flat print with spot gloss over
 the title text and the Indy Reads Books donations call-out.</p>
     </div>

  <div class="buttons-bar">
   <button class="tablinks buttons-bar-item button w3-light-grey" onclick="openImgtype(event, 'toyscardImage1')">Postcard</button>
   <button class="tablinks buttons-bar-item button" onclick="openImgtype(event, 'toyscardImage2')">Web Graphics</button>
  </div>

  <div id="toyscardImage1" class="w3-container imgtype">
     <img src="Cel%20%20%20Graphic%20Design_files/TOYS2014_postcard.jpg">
  </div>

  <div id="toyscardImage2" class="w3-container imgtype">
     <img src="Cel%20%20%20Graphic%20Design_files/TOYS2014_graphics.png">
  </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

I expect the openModal function to refresh upon action so that the w3-light-gray class is added to the Image1 item every time openModal runs. However that w3-light-gray attribute is sticking to the last interacted Image1 item.

Comment: Add your `HTML` to your post. Your code isn't of much help without it.

Comment: Please add a working example to be able to help you

Comment: @RyanWilson I've just added an example of the HTML for one of my modals. Code and layout-wise, almost all my modals are identical. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly and I'm not convinced that I do, you always want the first item to have the w3-light-gray class then don't include the first item in the iterator (still not sure why you're looping thru and removing the class if you always want it there?)

```
/*
if you only want the class on the first element in the array
single out the first item with imageArr[0] and scratch the for loop
*/
imageArr[0].classList.add('w3-light-gray')
```

for your 'However that w3-light-gray attribute is sticking to the last interacted Image1 item.' comment - you've got a click event target thats getting the 'w3-light-gray' class - this isn't required if i'm understanding your comment

```
evt.currentTarget.classList.add("w3-light-grey");
```

'Clicking around within multiple modals to move that w3-light-gray attribute means that technically the last interacted item contains that w3-light-grey attribute' ...huh?

ps. your question is convoluted and confusing - sometimes less is more, for example - I have a set of modals and when i do 'X' I want 'Y' to happen. My current implementation does this...yadayada...your code here...yadayada

Comment: Thank you for the help @mcgraw! It's hard to describe the issue clearly when I barely understand Javascript to begin with. So sorry! 

Everything within the openImgtype function, as far as I can tell, is working correctly. My issue is that the code within my openImgtype function is taking priority over my openModal function. Once the openModal function opens a modal with all the ‘tablinks’ items, it is functioning correctly. When I close out that modal and open a new one (with the openModal function), I want the 'w3-light-grey' class to ALWAYS snap to the 1st ‘tablinks’ item every time.

Comment: no worries - just trying to understand what you need.

is more than 1 modal open at a time? 
is it ok for more than 1 element to have the w3-light-gray class? or is that the only image you want that class on?

if you add this to the open modal method, when the function is called the first item in the array will get the class

   let targetImg = yourImageArray[0].classList.add('w3-light-gray')

Comment: @barfbats if my explanation answered your question would you please click the `up arrow` next to the answer or explain why it doesn't answer your question so that I can provide you with another. thank you

Comment: I think a visual example will help explain this much better than my words! https://codepen.io/barfbats/pen/PoYLaxr here, you'll see the "Desktop View" button should be in light gray (selected style) on every modal upon open, but that is not the case. I hope this helps!